# How can i upload Binary file like cert file as Config-map

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, configmap

How can i upload Binary file like cert file as Config-map

I am trying to upload Cert file like .p12 as config map but it's failing every time. After upload i do not see the file just entry.

Command that i used:

```
oc create configmap mmx-cert --from-file=xyz.p12
```

Failed.

Also used:

```
oc create configmap mmx-cert--from-file=game-special-key=example-files/xyz.p12
```

Also failed.

Comment: what's the oc command, why not `kubectl`, what's the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot, ConfigMaps cannot contain binary data on their own. You will need to encode it yourself and decode it on the other side, usually base64. Or just a Secret instead, which can handle binary data.

Comment: Oh, Can you please provide the commands to create secret and mount the same to any Mount path as file. Exactly like i was trying to do with config-map with my p12 cert file.

Comment: Literally just replace `create cm` with `create secret` :) And on your volume side, instead of `configMapRef` you use `secretRef`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what's the command `oc`, but if you are talking about `kubectl`, please make sure you feed the proper parameter

```
kubectl create configmap mmx-cert --from-env-file=path/to/xyz.p12
```

Please go through `help` as well, the parameter `--from-file` is based on folder, not file.

```
$ kubectl create configmap --help
...
# Create a new configmap named my-config based on folder bar
kubectl create configmap my-config --from-file=path/to/bar
```

Comment: `oc` is the OpenShift version of `kubectl`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i done.

1) Adding the cert to stage CAE:

With the cert in the same directory as you are running the oc command:

```
oc create secret generic mmx-cert --from-file='cert.p12'
```

2) Add the secret volume:

The next step is to create a volume for the secret.  As a test, I was able to use the oc command to create the volume on the apache nodes.  Since the apache nodes have a deployment config, it was straight forward.  I took that test setup, and manually added it to the app pods.  The pieces I added to the deployment yaml were:

```
- mountPath: /opt/webserver/cert/nonprod/
  name: mmxcert-volume


- name: mmxcert-volume
  secret:
  defaultMode: 420
  secretName: mmx-cert
```

3) Verify the cert

```
md5sum cert.p12
```

Answer (score 1):

IDK if the accepted answer changed over time **BUT** you actually can put binary files on cms base64 coded you don't actually have to do anything after that e.g.:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
binaryData:
  elasticsearch.keystore: P9dsFxZlbGFzdGljc2VhcmNoLmtleXN0b3JlAAAABAAAAAC/AAAAQM5hkNkN7WjdNRwa/vKIte4mnBrWKZxzuqTdvNdneTWzZyQU+TIquP+ZlV1zCOGm2Jbdg+wMNcWqTQY4LvoSKHEAAAAMo5XONlIK6969bNQFAAAAZ6Cn+jnDe29K0W4a0unPodSljz+W+tRxgD59+oFnt17vN9hSutTbk1lzCJNiwnhK5mliHmS5Ie/9dhWfnI+vhkzXvFAYauvFxS7aJ9L3uKw3opFUtSrPY76fAXPcEYMGp8TcTceMZK7AKJPoAAAAAAAAAAAGacI8
data:
  elasticsearch.yml: |
    ...
```

source: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/